# Is there a With statement in Javascript like ther is in VB

Tags: javascript, vba

I can hold my own in VBA and now I am venturing out into Javascript.

In VBA if you are going to use the same object you can prefence it with and `With` statement and not need to reference the object again. For example;

```
With oSomeForm
   .Name = "some neat name"
   .Refresh
End With   ' oSomeForm
```

Is there something similar for Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [there is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Using it is strongly discouraged for the reasons described in [this YUI blog post by Douglas Crockford](https://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/), and you can't use it in strict mode (which you should be using, and which is the default in modules), but it's there.

```
with (someForm) {
    name = "some neat name";
    // ...
}
```

Note that you don't use a leading `.` as you do in VB.

---

Instead of using `with`, consider just repeating the variable name. If it's long, or you're using `with` on the result of an expression, you might use a local alias. For instance, in ES2015 and later you can use a local `const` in a block:

```
{
    const o = /*...the long identifier or expression...*/;
    o.name = "some neat name";
}
```

---

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript) is a very good community-edited resource for JavaScript information

Comment: I understand. Using `With` in JS is bad practice so I will forego it's use.

Comment: is it still a bad practice in 2021 ?

Comment: @AlanDaniel - Nothing's changed in this regard other than that modules have widespread support now, meaning more code is in strict mode by default and thus cannot use `with`. (And I strongly recommend using strict mode even outside of modules, for the other benefits it brings, not least the fact it fixes the horror of implicit globals -- assigning to a completely undeclared identifier is an error in strict mode, but creates a global variable in loose mode.)